# Export RadRichTextBox content in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, richtextbox

I want to export Telerik `RadRichTextBox` to a variable.

```
(new RtfFormatProvider()).Export(RadRichTextBox1.Document)
```

But this code will show this error:

> Cannot convert from RadDocument to RadFlowDocument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't reference the appropriate `RtfFormatProvider` class.

Check your `using`s, or explitly call:

```
(new Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Rtf.RtfFormatProvider()).Export(RadRichTextBox1.Document)
```